# what are the remote sharing servers available for x11 display in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel, xorg, vnc, vncviewer

I am using x11vnc server on ubuntu 16.04 running on beagle bone board. When i connect using vnc viewer client, display connected to board is flickering.

Are there any other servers available which can be used with x11 display.

Comment: IMO FreeNX is fastest and most secure.

Comment: could you please share the details about IMO FreeNX

Comment: I checked quickly, nx packages not available for arm architecture